# Using TFS and Git, is it possible to pull only files which have changed since the last deploy to the build server?

Tags: git, deployment, tfs

We are using TFS and Git. The repository size is several gigabytes. It is full of PDF files, no code. Every time a deployment runs, it clones the entire repository, even if only a single 1mb PDF file has changed. The deploy process is taking way too long. This is unacceptable for this team. Is there a way for the build server to pull only the files which have changed in the repository when it needs to do a deployment? We are wracking our heads over here and have not found a solution yet.

Comment: Why are you storing a collection of PDF files in git?  That's not what git does, and it will not do it well.  You can make it less bad by using git LFS; but even so, and even if you find a workable solution to your immediate build problem, this is just going to cause more problems as it grows... and in return, you're getting pretty much none of the benefits of git

Comment: Where should we store them? How would we configure TFS build/release to pull from some source other than Git? It seems to require Git as its source.

Comment: Did you try to set Clean in your tfs build definitiion? Set this to false if you want to define an incremental build to improve performance. This will not delete the source you got before.